# When I'm in the activity and turn internet on and off, then null pointer exception occurs

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
public class NRclientsFragment extends Fragment{

JSONObject json;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
NRclientsCustomList adapter;
ListView listview;

private static final String TAG_CLIENTNAME = "Client Name";
private static final String TAG_COMPANYNAME = "Company Name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
private static final String TAG_CONTACTNO = "Contact No";

public NRclientsFragment(){}

ConnectionDetector cd;
Boolean isInternetPresent;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nrclients, container,      false);
    Log.i("sgs", "Process Started ");

    listview = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.nrclientslv);
    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    adapter = new NRclientsCustomList(getActivity(), arraylist);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (ConnectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {

    new NRclientTask().execute();

    }

    else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Try Again NR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

    return v;
}

private class NRclientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pd;
    HttpResponseResult response;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...",
        false, false);
}


protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

Log.i("sgs", "Calling Web Service for NR Clients Fragment");

SoapWebServiceCallNoPara serviceCall = new SoapWebServiceCallNoPara();

response = serviceCall.CallService(getActivity(),
        SoapWebServiceCallNoPara.WEB_NRCLIENTS);
Log.i("sgs", "Got response from web service");

try {

    if( response == null || response.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Null Values",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        return null;
    }

    else{

    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response.getResponse());

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

        map.put("clientname", obj.getString(TAG_CLIENTNAME));
        map.put("companyname", obj.getString(TAG_COMPANYNAME));
        map.put("email", obj.getString(TAG_EMAIL));
        map.put("contactno", obj.getString(TAG_CONTACTNO));

        arraylist.add(map);
        Log.i("sgs", "All set to adapter");

        Log.i("sgs", obj.getString(TAG_CLIENTNAME));
        Log.i("sgs", obj.getString(TAG_COMPANYNAME));
        Log.i("sgs", obj.getString(TAG_EMAIL));
        Log.i("sgs", obj.getString(TAG_CONTACTNO));

    }}
  }             
  catch (JSONException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return null;
}

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         pd.dismiss();

}

}

}
```

Output of logcat:

```
05-12 11:55:16.597: E/test(30875): Exception
05-12 11:55:16.597: D/dalvikvm(30875): threadid=13: notify debugger
05-12 11:55:16.597: D/dalvikvm(30875): threadid=13 (AsyncTask #3): calling run()
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875): java.lang.RuntimeException: An      error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at com.example.sgs.slidingmenu.NRclientsFragment$NRclientTask.doInBackground(NRclientsFragment.java:104)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at com.example.sgs.slidingmenu.NRclientsFragment$NRclientTask.doInBackground(NRclientsFragment.java:1)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-12 11:55:16.599: E/AndroidRuntime(30875):    ... 4 more
05-12 11:55:16.727: V/InputMethodManager(30875): focusOut:   android.widget.ListView{4146c400 VFED.VC. .F...... -324,0-36,778 #7f0a0002   app:id/list_slidermenu} mServedView=android.widget.ListView{4146c400 VFED.VC.  .F...... -324,0-36,778 #7f0a0002 app:id/list_slidermenu} winFocus=false
05-12 11:55:16.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(30875): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-12 11:55:16.882: D/OpenGLRenderer(30875): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-12 11:55:16.915: D/OpenGLRenderer(30875): Flushing caches (mode 1)
05-12 11:55:16.920: D/OpenGLRenderer(30875): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875): Activity   com.example.sgs.MainActivity has leaked window   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41785fc8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-513,144} that was originally added here
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.sgs.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41785fc8 V.E.....  R......D 0,0-513,144} that was originally added here
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:412)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:293)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:104)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at com.example.sgs.slidingmenu.NRclientsFragment$NRclientTask.onPreExecute(NRclientsFragment.java:79)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at com.example.sgs.slidingmenu.NRclientsFragment.onCreateView(NRclientsFragment.java:60)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-12 11:55:16.929: E/WindowManager(30875):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Generally it works fine only issue comes when i switch network on and off

Comment: then handle that problem in your class. for AsyncTask first check if Internet is available or not. if available then execute AsyncTast of of not available then show some error message.

Comment: Chiraj I guess I did the same. When no Internet it shows message but when internet comes back it throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

I was making mistake here 
if( response == null || response.equals(""))

when i changed above line to 
if( response.getResponse() == null || response.getResponse().equals(""))

problem was solved.